# Re-reading file when cycling over a file object in Python

Tags: python

From this context:

```
import itertools
lines = itertools.cycle(open('filename'))
```

I'm wondering how I can implement that same 'feature' but rereading the file when it reaches the end, so if the file got changed since first iteration it's reloaded before starts another cycle. (hope I've explained well)

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.starmap(open, itertools.repeat(("filename",))))
```

or:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.starmap(lambda: open("filename"), itertools.repeat(())))
```

You can also write a generator comprehension (I think I like this best!):

```
(line for _ in itertools.repeat(()) for line in open("filename"))
```

Here's the imperative (statement-based) equivalent:

```
def cycle_file(filename):
    while True:
        for line in open(filename):
            yield line
```

Or, with Python 3.3 (using [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) subgenerator delegation):

```
def cycle_file(filename):
    while True:
        yield from open(filename)
```

One problem with all of these is that (on a GC platform e.g. Jython) the file will not be closed until the file object is GCed, which could happen some time later.  To prevent the open file leaking, you have to call `close` on it or use a contextmanager (`with` statement).  This comes out naturally in the imperative form:

```
def cycle_file(filename):
    while True:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line
```

or

```
def cycle_file(filename):
    while True:
        with open(filename) as f:
            yield from f
```

Trying to close the file with a generator comprehension becomes highly contrived:

```
(line for f in (itertools.chain(f, (f for f in (f,) if f.close() and False))
                for f in (open("filename") for _ in itertools.repeat(())))
 for line in f)
```

It'd be nice if Python had a way to specify that an `open`ed file should close itself upon reaching the end of the file, or a way to tell a contextmanager-iterator to close itself on `StopIteration`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer the last way too, seems more easier to understand! :)
Also liked the Python 3.3 version code, a good reminder that I need to update myself! Thanks!! :)

Comment: `while True` seems the most readable. You could adapt it for Python < 3.3: `for line in open(filename)): yield line`

Comment: to avoid fd leaks `with` statement could be used

Comment: OK, done - I think the imperative version starts to come out on top

Comment: Yeah, now I've good points to choose the tweaked imperative version (trully the most readable one!), thanks again for all the support! :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
def cycle_file(f):
    while True:
        ln = f.readline()
        if ln == "":
            f.seek(0)
            continue
        yield ln
```

Except that it might be nice to put in a check for empty files, which I'll leave to you.

Comment: This would yield the empty string at the end, right?  Could be a bug or a feature.

Comment: @DSM: I forgot a `continue` statement. Thanks.

Comment: this might miss changes if the file is replaced (`tail -f` vs. `tail -F`)

Comment: Although I've chosen the generator comprehension way from @ecatmur, I liked your code intuitiveness! Thanks for the empty file tip, if you hadn't adviced I probably would've forgotten it! :)