# Looping over resource in python

Tags: python, for-loop, with-statement

Is there a shorter way to do the following `for-with` combination:

```
for resource in gen_resources():
    with resource:
        DoWork1(resource)
        .
        .
        DoWorkN(resource)
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid the extra line + indentation.

Resource could be anything that has to be finalized upon leaving the loop iteration (open file, active object, etc.)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332192/re-reading-file-when-cycling-over-a-file-object-in-python

Comment: Why does this matter?  I know you've said you want to avoid the extra indentation, but why does that matter?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, because it can be easy to forget to use `with`. The resources I'm iterating over are not classic resources and a user could easily forget to call their `close()` method or to use `with`

Comment: @Albert In this case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12897579/296974) indeed seems to be the best one, when this facility is integrated into `gen_resources()`.

Comment: @Albert:  Something here doesn't add up for me.  You don't trust your users to use `with` or to call `close()`, but you would trust them to wrap the iterable in `iterate_with`?  Wouldn't they be just as likely to forget to use the generator function?  I'm not saying that you are wrong to mistrust your users, just that the proposed solution does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Depending on the solution. The accepted answer for instance eliminates the requirement to use `with` from the user side. And now to philosophy. I believe that the better tools people have, the more likely they are to use them.

Comment: @Albert:  The user does not write the for-loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a generator function that performs the `with` statement on each element:

```
def iterate_with(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        with element:
            yield element
```

Use:

```
for resource in iterate_with(gen_resources()):
    DoWork(resource)
```

I'd probably still use your original code over this, since it may not be clear to the reader of the code that the `with` statement is used here.

Comment: What happens if the the generator is not fully exhausted?

Comment: @Albert: When the generator is released (because there are no more references to it) it will close and the current element's `__exit__` will be called. This will also happen if you break out of the `for` loop shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Only because you have one statement inside the `with`:

```
for resource in gen_resources():
    with resource:  DoWork(resource)
```

This seems to be generally frowned upon, but I have no idea why - `for` and `if` can do the same thing, and it's pretty convenient...

Comment: I used `DoWork` for demonstration purposes. See edited question.

Comment: @Izkata the `with` must start its own line, it is a syntax error otherwise. You can only make an indented block into a single line if nothing in that block has itself an indented block.